# unable to create new project blank app android in visual studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I Xamarin installed in visual studio 2015.
Through a new option in visual studio 2015 when I create an Android project, the following error message.

"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

In addition, the SDK-Manager in the photo below I do not see this is a problem or not. But none of the following messages created will not install android api level.

```
Preparing to install archives
```

Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 25.2.2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 301642481 bytes, got 1487 bytes.
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 416
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 416
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 7'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 7'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 10'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22, revision 10'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 10'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.

[status SDK-Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Ehc.jpg)

Comment: Seems like your download stopped... How stable is your net connection? Was there a power flash during an update?

Comment: my net connection is stable